# InvokeMethod with List<string> as the parameter

Tags: c#, workflow

Try to call the following method from the Activity Workflow:

```
namespace Namespace1
{
 public partial class Class1
 {
  public static void Method1(List<string> p1){}
 }
}
```

I specify in visual Workflow Editor:

- TargetType = Namespace1.Class1
- Method name = Method1
- Parameters: Direction:In; Type:List; and corresponding Value.

But receive the following Error:
'Class1' does not have a public static method named 'Method1' matching the parameter types, generic type arguments, and generic type constraints supplied to InvokeMethod 'Method1'.

1. Is the signature of the Method1 correct?
2. What is the reason of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Name your parameter:  `List<string> myList`

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with Visual Workflow Editor, however it is likely, as Xela stated, that you need to provide a parameter name:

```
public static void Method1(List<string> myList){}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there actually was no error. The reason of presence of error in Error List was that the error disappears only after successful building of the project. In my case errors in other parts of code prevented from successful building.